# Can I dynamically modify the account activation link that Joomla sends and redirect to different pages after activation

Tags: joomla

I have a website where people can buy different online courses and as it is, when a non-logged in user clicks to buy a course, he is told to register or log in. On registering, a click on the activation link in the email, takes one to a fixed page on the site (which I know how to change) and the user has to re-select the course that they want to buy and then proceed with the buying process.

What I would like is:

- When a course is chosen for purchase, the "Register" link on that course's page should dynamically have some parameters appended to it which indicates which course has been chosen.
- Now when a user submits the Registration page, these parameters should get appended to the activation link which gets sent out to the user.
- When the user now clicks the activation link, he/she should get auto logged in and the buying process for the previously chosen course should resume. So the user should not have to re-select the course he wants to buy.

I am using Joomla 2.5.

Thanks in advance for everyone's help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can work like

When the user choose any of the course that Id passed through registration page and store it as hidden filed or (you can use session). after registration the registration model `com_users/models/registration.php` have a `function register()` that have the section for managing activation link to email just append your additional params must be encoded.

Then next activation verification function is in `com_users/controllers/registration.php` with `activate()` just check the param and activate it.

another suggestion is just keep the user id and course id in additional table to prevent someone try to access it from activation urls only .

If you prefer session usage will be like

```
$session = JFactory::getSession();
$session->set('session_var','session_val');
echo $session->get('session_var');
```

Hope it give some idea.

Comment: Thank you Jobin for your reply. Will play with the suggested solution and get back.